# How-to remote connect from a PC into a Windows 10 Mobile Phone

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I would like to remote control a Windows 10 Mobile Phone from a PC. I only found the remote Desktop App which allows a Phone to remote control a PC.

Connecting via RDC to the IP address shown in "Phone, ..., For Developers, Device portal" does not work.

Comment: what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I find it easier to do initial phone configurations  (like entering complex passwords) using a real keyboard via RDC. I find it more convenient to test my apps on phones using a RDC window on one of my PC's monitors. To show the phone screen in presentations.

Comment: try this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42536

Comment: This tool "My Screen App for Windows Phone" has an .msi installer. How is one supposed to install this on a W10M phone. And according the description it would only solve the presentation problem.

Comment: you install this on your PC

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by "...install the Project My Screen app on your Windows device ...". This app does show the phone screen on a PC and allows controlling it via mouse and the phone keyboard. Which is good for presentations. It seems not to allow using the PC keyboard though.

Comment: send Feedback to MS with the feedback hub app and request that you can use your PC keyboard

Comment: @PeterMeinl were you able to find anything better in the last year? I have the same question except I want to access the W10M device remotely, via the network. Our support staff needs to support the devices on our campus and therefore, on our wifi network and remote access to the W10M device seems to be something that is not readily available.

Comment: @Michael: I only found the feature "Projecting to this PC" mentioned in my Answer. With this you can on a PC generally enable to project to it and then connect from a Windows Phone to it. The connection attempt triggers a dialog "allow connection from phone on the PC". When connected one can control the phone using mouse and keystrokes. This does not seem to help for the scenario you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/whats-new-settings-app-windows-10-anniversary-update) there is a new feature **Project to this PC** in the Win10 Anniversary Update:

"
*On Settings > System for the Anniversary Update there is a new Project to this PC settings page. This is a new feature in the new version of the operating system, which is essentially another way to remote access devices. The feature allows to project your Windows phone or computer to another Windows 10 PC with access to control their keyboard and mouse using the Connect app.*
"

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging (searching), I ran across a company called ISL Online. The link is here: [ISL Online](http://www.islonline.com/remote-support/mobile/windows-mobile.htm)

For my scenario, I want to remote control the W10M device via the internet/network, similar to how you would using Remote Desktop Connection. This seems to be one of the few, if not the only companies out there that has a solution for this.

I am now using it and it works great.